# Circle Summation (30 Points) InterviewStree Puzzle cont

Tags: c++, algorithm

Further to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711239/circle-summation-30-points-interviewstree-puzzle/8712670#8712670) 
I solved it in following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdio.h>


int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    int T; // number of test cases
    std::cin >> T;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < T; i++) {
        int N; // number of childrens
        std::cin >> N;
        int M; // number of rounds
        std::cin >> M;
        long long childrens[50];
        for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
            std::cin >> childrens[j];

        int pos = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
            long long childs[50];
            for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
                childs[j] = childrens[j];
            for ( int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                int left  = ( pos     == 0)  ? N - 1  : pos - 1;
                int right = ( pos + 1 >= N ) ? 0      : pos + 1;
                childs[pos] = (childs[pos] + childs[left] + childs[right])% 1000000007;
                pos++;
                pos   = ( pos >= N ) ? 0 : pos;
            }
            std::copy(childs ,childs + N ,std::ostream_iterator<long long>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the `M` can be `10^9`, My code is going to take lot of time to finish, What are the various ways I can optize this.

Comment: hehe, I'm trying the same problem. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdio.h>


int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    int T; // number of test cases
    std::cin >> T;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < T; i++) {
        int N; // number of childrens
        std::cin >> N;
        int M; // number of rounds
        std::cin >> M;
```

Why split this across two lines instead of `std::cin >> N >> M;`?

```
        long long childrens[50];
```

I missed this in my first submissions and tried using 32 bit integers. It didn't work so well...

```
        for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
            std::cin >> childrens[j];

        int pos = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
            long long childs[50];
            for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++ ) 
                childs[j] = childrens[j];
            for ( int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
                int left  = ( pos     == 0)  ? N - 1  : pos - 1;
```

You can use `left = (pos + N - 1) % N` which works thanks to modular math.

```
                int right = ( pos + 1 >= N ) ? 0      : pos + 1;
```

You can use `right = (pos + 1) % N`

```
                childs[pos] = (childs[pos] + childs[left] + childs[right])% 1000000007;
                pos++;
                pos   = ( pos >= N ) ? 0 : pos;
```

You can use `pos = (pos + 1) % N`

```
            }
            std::copy(childs ,childs + N ,std::ostream_iterator<long long>(std::cout," "));
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Generally, writing brute force solutions for a site like Interviewstreet is a waste of time.   Its not like you can write your brute force solution, and then optimize it so that it will run fast enough. You need to come up with a completely different approach.

Since Interviewstreet is trying to test your abilities I'm not going to share my solution. (Unless you have a solution for the Meeting Point problem, then I'll trade :P) But I will give a hint: think back to linear algebra.